# Verificar se objeto faz parte de classe que implementa determinada interface

Tags: java, interface

Preciso criar uma condição para saber se determinado objeto faz parte de uma classe que implementa certa interface. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7275905/3517631) também, segue os exemplos:

```
interface I1 { }

interface I2 { }

class C implements I1, I2 { }

C c = new C();

boolean isC = (c instanceof C);   //true
boolean isI1 = (c instanceof I1); //true
boolean isI2 = (c instanceof I2); //true
```